# getting a large version of message and mail icon ios

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a place where I can get the iOS Message and Mail app icons? I checked in the Apple Developer Resources and Human Interface Guidelines but couldn't find anything? (I know that you can use them with the `UIActivityViewController`, but I need them in a separate `UIImageView` as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to an icon package for iOS 5 that I used in one of my apps:
http://iconsparadise.com/iphone-free-icons/iphone-4-ios-5-app-icons/

Pretty straight forward download. Good luck.